# How can I keep a local and remote folder (with subfolders) totally synchronized using rsync on Linux?

Tags: linux, rsync

How can I keep a local and remote folder (with subfolders) totally synchronized using rsync on Linux?

So I have a local folder A and a remote folder B.

Regardless of where the change occurs I want the newest files and folders to synchronize with the other machine.

Example:

Text file is updated in folder A. Within minutes folder B is updated accordingly.

Or:

Text file is updated in folder B. Within minutes folder A is updated accordingly.

It doesn't have to be exactly instantaneous so no need for inotifywait or similar tools. I will make a cron script most likely.

But how would the rsync part look like and especially all those pesky flags?

Vesa

Comment: `rsync` is only designed to do one-directional syncing. I'd take a look at [Unison](http://www.cis.upenn.edu/~bcpierce/unison/) instead.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add a rsync command as a cron. This will sync the changes automatically between the local folder A and a remote folder B. Since you want to set the synchronisation both ways, you need to use the rsync to sync from remote to your server as well. So basically 2 rsyncs.

```
rsync -rtuv <path to folder A>   <user>@<ip/hostname>:<path to folder B>
rsync -rtuv <user>@<ip/hostname>:<path to folder B>   <path to folder A>
```

Just run it twice, with "newer" mode (-u or --update flag) plus -t (to copy file modified time), -r (for recursive folders), and -v (for verbose output to see what it is doing).

You can also check Unison.
http://www.cis.upenn.edu/~bcpierce/unison/index.html